# max() operation on spark without reducing the row count

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata

Suppose that we have a dataset of three columns which are customer id, action and action time.

```
 1, ACTION_1, 100
 1, ACTION_2, 101
 1, ACTION_3, 102
 2, ACTION_1, 100
 2, ACTION_2, 105
 2, ACTION_3, 102
 3, ACTION_1, 120
 3, ACTION_2, 111
 3, ACTION_3, 103
```

We want to get the last action time of each customer while filtering some specific action like ACTION_2. Like below:

```
 1, ACTION_2, 102
 2, ACTION_2, 105
 3, ACTION_2, 120
```

we are looking forward to learn any type of solution for this issue.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: if we try to get the last action time we lose the action data we want which is ACTION_2 in our case.

Comment: So just get the last  `action time` for each customer and create a new column with "ACTION_2" value

Comment: The reason that we want this solution is because each action type has its own count. For example (ACTION_2, 5) 5 times. We omitted this information for simplicity.

Comment: you need a ranking function over a window

Answer (score 0):

Creating the dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

data = [
 (1, 'ACTION_1', 100),
 (1, 'ACTION_2', 101),
 (1, 'ACTION_3', 102),
 (2, 'ACTION_1', 100),
 (2, 'ACTION_2', 105),
 (2, 'ACTION_3', 102),
 (3, 'ACTION_1', 120),
 (3, 'ACTION_2', 111),
 (3, 'ACTION_3', 103)]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['customerid', 'action', 'actiontime'])
df.show()
```

Using max function over Window partioned by customer-id

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
w = Window.partitionBy(df.customerid)

df1 = df.withColumn('actiontime', max('actiontime').over(w))
df1.show()
```

Filtering the data on the condition:

```
df2 = df1.where(df1.action == 'ACTION_2')
df2.show()
+----------+--------+----------+
|customerid|  action|actiontime|
+----------+--------+----------+
|         1|ACTION_2|       102|
|         3|ACTION_2|       120|
|         2|ACTION_2|       105|
+----------+--------+----------+
```